# insert a row based on column value in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have three tables. In table one I have id, name, and two columns. In the other table I have id, name, etc.. Similarly the third one. The values of the tables are listed below

[image]

In the above image the column nameEEE consist of same values.

Another table has a column like nameECE consist of same values.

My issue is:

I have textbox controls. When I input eee in the textbox the values should be inserted to the respective table where the column consist of eee values. This can be done using `if else` condition but in the case of 20 tables how to write the query

insert query is something like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-CEUQVES;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
con.Open();

string projid = projectidText.Text;
string videourl = videoText.Text;


string filename = Path.GetFileName(abstractFile.PostedFile.FileName);
abstractFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("documents/mini/" + filename));

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ece(projectid, video, abstract) values(@id, @video, @abstract)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = projid;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@video", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = videourl;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@abstract", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = filename;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

By using if else it can be done but the code will be huge.

Comment: You could generate the SQL queries dynamically on the server side based on the user entry, but you'd have serious security issues.  Dare I ask WHY you need to do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are actually using.  I removed the extraneous database tags and added sql.

Comment: Mainly it is to develop a website and add table values by the admin based on the column field. @Dave

Comment: Okay, but which are you using?  mysql or sql-server?  And how is .NET taking to the database?  Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @Crazyy.Net if you want to add RDBMS specific tags, then add the proper one, not random ones or explain in the question why you have more than one product tag listed. Reverted back to Gordon's version.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL sever 2014

Comment: show us some of your code. Are you using c# or vb? What does your insert statement look like

Comment: Updated my question. Its c#

Answer (score 1):

You can construct your SQL query like this:

```
string commandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (projectID{0}, video{0}, abstract{0}, values(@id, @video, @abstract)", UserEnteredTableName);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
```

But you shouldn't.  It leaves you critically open to SQL injection, if a user puts valid SQL into the textbox where they enter the table name.

I've done similar projects where the users create the field names and values, and I've had success mapping it like:

```
table CustomTables
tableID tableName
------- ---------
1       eee
2       ece

table CustomFields
FieldID tableID rowNumber fieldName fieldValue
------- ------- --------- --------- ----------
1       1       1         projectid 1
2       1       1         name      eee
3       1       1         video     ssssas
3       1       1         abs       xadads
4       1       2         projectid 2
5       1       2         name      eee
6       1       2         video     jsdksj
7       1       2         abs       jdxksk
8       1       3         projectid 4
9       1       3         name      eee
10      1       3         video     rvrge
11      1       3         abs       dtydd
12      2       1         projectid 1
13      2       1         name      ece
14      2       1         video     werwerwerw
15      2       1         abs       etertertf
```

(You might not need the "name" field, if all it does is store the name of the custom table, because you're storing that name in the CustomTables table)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you combine all your tables into one. So instead of this:

```
table EEE:
projectidEEE nameEEE videoEEE absEEE
------------ ------- -------- ------
 1            eee     blah     gorp

table ECE:
projectidECE nameECE videoECE absECE
------------ ------- -------- ------
 1            ece     blick    blork
```

You would add a column and combine the tables like so:

```
table ProjectSomething:
projectidECE SomethingId nameECE videoECE absECE
------------ ----------- ------- -------- ------
 1             1          eee     blah     gorp
 1             2          ece     blick    blork
```

Where `SomethingId` 1 is `EEE` and 2 is `ECE`, as foreign keys from a table listing each of the 20 types.

I suspect that you could drop the `nameECE` column if it really has the values `EEE` and `ECE` that are the same for every row in each table (it's not clear from your fake data). If the rows are different, then of course the column can stay, or be normalized if there are some duplicates but not all.